# DIV transparent border not showing underlying background in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border, cross-browser

I have a div with background solid color and transparent border.

In IE8+ and Chrome, transparent border shows the underlying background color.  However, in IE7 border is transparent: no background is shown behind the border.

How can I make IE7 display the border like IE8+, Chrome, and "modern" browsers do?

Here's my HTML and CSS (See it working on http://jsfiddle.net/hG82h/1/):

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>    
</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #AAA;
}
#div1 {
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
#div2 {
    border: 10px solid #666;
}​
```

Comment: What's wrong with using a padding? http://jsfiddle.net/hG82h/2/

Comment: So brilliant and simple... It worked like a charm for me, post an answer if you want me to accept it, ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `padding` property instead, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hG82h/2/).

But mention the difference between box models in IE, Chrome and Mozilla. I suggest to read and use [this](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/), otherwise the result depends on the browser.